# discordjs message.guild.roles.size returns null in serverinfo command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

It might be new to Discord.js v12. I've upgraded from v11 to v12 and I found out my `serverinfo` total roles returned `null`.

Source for roles part:

```
.addField("Role Count:", `${message.guild.roles.size}`, true)
```

`cmd` did not return an error.

I checked `guild.roles` in https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#collection but I didn't understand what it means by Manager:

> guild.roles is now a Manager instead of a Collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you did your research, you missed that it mentions on the top of the page that *v12 introduces the concept of managers, you will no longer be able to directly use collection methods*. https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache

You will now have to directly **ask for cache** on a manager before trying to use collection methods:

```js
.addField("Role Count:", `${message.guild.roles.cache.size}`, true)
```